# spacey model for nlp in python not yielding entity the label

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have the following pandas dataframe- df1. The column sentence consists of character vectors

```
       Sentence                   
       Hello Xime    
       Work  Yime    
       New   Zime
```

I have used an nlp model using spacey called nlp_mod. I have created a second column after training the model as follows

```
       df1["Col1"]=[nlp(i).ents for i  in df1["Sentence"]]
       Sentence      Col1              
       Hello Xime    (X,)
       Work  Yime    (X,)
       New   Zime    (X,)
```

The above code is able to separate the entities. I am unable to get the entity labels when I try

```
  df1["lab"]=[ent.label_ for ents   in df1["Col1"]]
```

I am getting the following error

```
 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ent'
```

I request someone to guide me suitably as to where my error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlp(i).ents` returns a tuple of identified entities. So you have to loop through the identified entities to retrieve their properties.

```
[[(ent.label_) for ent in ents] for ents in df["Col1"]]
```

Working Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Sentence': ["Hello Xime", "iPhone is an Apple Phone", "New Delhi is the capital of India"] })
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df["Col1"] = [nlp(i).ents for i  in df["Sentence"]]
df["lab"] = [[(ent.label_) for ent in ents] for ents in df["Col1"]]
print (df)
```

Output:

```
    Sentence                             Col1                   lab
0   Hello Xime                           ()                     []
1   iPhone is an Apple Phone             ((iPhone), (Apple))    [ORG, ORG]
2   New Delhi is the capital of India   ((New, Delhi), (India)) [GPE, GPE]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be like a nested loop . Works beautifully